# BaseSerializer.save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given; Django rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

Here is my error message

```
TypeError at /users/auth/registration/
BaseSerializer.save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/auth/registration/
Django Version: 4.0.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
BaseSerializer.save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception Location: C:\Users\Chika Precious\.virtualenvs\vicsite-3EqYD9rF\lib\site-packages\dj_rest_auth\registration\views.py, line 85, in perform_create
```

**Serializers**

Here is my serializer class

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'occupation', 'phone', 'sex']
```

Comment: Can you share your view? Did you change the default serializer of the register view?

Comment: i did'nt need to write any view code for registration as directed in the dj_rest_auth. Or do i need to write a view code for it ?

Answer (score -1):

override the save method and
in the CustomSerializer inherit RegisterSerializer using this code: from `dj_rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer`